# FFmpeg python: different length after fps changed and interpolated

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

For my application I'm adapting the code from the ffmpeg-python github for [tensorflow streaming](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/tensorflow_stream.py).

It basically decodes each frame of your input, lets you process it with python, and encodes it again.

To optimize things I'm adding a *fps* filter at the input to get half the fps, so I can process only half the frames, then interpolate frames in the encoder with *minterpolate* to get the original fps.

My decoder looks like this:

```
def decoder(in_filename):
args = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(in_filename)
    .filter('fps', fps=30/2)
     (... more filters in between ...)
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
    .compile()
)
return subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And my encoder after processing the frames with python:

```
def encoder(out_filename, width, height):

args = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
    .filter('minterpolate', fps=30)
    .filter('fps',fps=30)
    .output(out_filename, pix_fmt='rgb24')
    .overwrite_output()
    .compile()
)
return subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

After that I horizontally stack the original input with the processed video

```
subprocess.run("ffmpeg -i {} -i {} -filter_complex hstack=inputs=2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 {}".format(in_filename,out_filename,"out.mp4"))
```

Here's the problem:  The "processed" video is faster and ends before the original. It's like they follow the same timestamp but it never actually interpolated frames. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoder `.input()` must specify its frame rate to match the decoder framerate (15 frames/s). Currently it's using whatever the default framerate of the `rawvideo` encoder.

In FFmpeg, that is to use `-r 15` *input* option. Not sure what it is in `ffmpeg-python` but could simply be `r=15` keyword argument.

P.S., `.filter('fps',fps=30)` is redundant.

Comment: This was it. Appreciate it.